# Problems with jar file

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest, java-3d

The problem isn't creating the jar file but to make it work. Because I use Java 3D i need the jar file to get the Java 3D classes but I can't seem to get it to work. I have set up the classpath properly and I have also tried to set the class path in the manifest txt with

```
Class-Path: C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\vecmath.jar;C:\Users\Censored\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\build\classes\Game\Main.class
```

I don't know if I do something wrong in the manifest file because when I press enter two times after `Class-Path:` I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

But if I don't press enter any time after `Class-Path:` I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D
```

Or have I done something wrong in the main method?

This is my hole code:

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Sphere;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private Image image;
    private Timer timer;
    private BallJump ball;
    private ThisPanel panel;
    private boolean inMenu = true;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main m = new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        setFocusable(true);
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("Ball Jump.png");
        panel = new ThisPanel();
        ball = new BallJump();
        image = ii.getImage();
        timer = new Timer(5,this);
        timer.start();
        setSize(600,600);
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        setVisible(true);
        repaint();
    }

    private class ThisPanel extends JPanel{

        public ThisPanel(){
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false), "pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true), "released");

            am.put("pressed", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(inMenu == true){
                        inMenu = false;
                        remove(panel);
                        ball.setAlive(true);
                        add(ball);            
                        setVisible(true); 
                    }

                    if (ball.isAlive() != true){ 
                        setSize(600,600);                     
                        setVisible(true);
                        repaint();
                        remove(ball);
                        ball = new BallJump();
                        add(ball); 
                        repaint();
                    } 
                }
            });

            am.put("released", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(inMenu == true){
                        inMenu = false;
                        remove(panel);
                        ball.setAlive(true);
                        add(ball);            
                        setVisible(true); 
                    }

                    if (ball.isAlive() != true){ 
                        remove(ball);
                        ball = new BallJump();
                        add(ball);
                        setVisible(true);
                        repaint();    
                    }
                }
            });

            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocusInWindow();        
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 600);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(inMenu == true){         
                Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            }    
        }
    }
}

class BallJump extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
    private TransformGroup objTrans,objTrans2, objTrans3, objTrans4, objTrans5, objTrans6, objTrans7;
    private Transform3D trans = new Transform3D();
    private BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot2 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot3 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot4 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot5 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot6 = new BranchGroup();
    private BranchGroup objRoot7 = new BranchGroup();
    private SimpleUniverse u;
    private Canvas3D c;
    private BranchGroup scene, scene2, scene3, scene4, scene5, scene6, scene7;
    private Sphere sphere, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4, sphere5, sphere6, sphere7;
    private float height = 0.0f, sign = 1.0f, xloc = 0.0f;
    private float height2 = 0.0f, sign2 = -1.0f;
    private float rightX, right, rightDx, leftX, left, leftDx, rightX2, leftX2;
    private boolean isAlive = true;
    private JLabel scoreLabel;
    private JLabel label;
    private int score = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean isEndscreen = true;


    public boolean isAlive(){
        return isAlive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean isAlive){
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph(){
        Color3f ambientColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.6f,0.0f,0.0f);
        Color3f emissiveColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
        Color3f diffuseColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.8f,0.0f,0.4f);
        Color3f specularColourRSphere = new Color3f(0.3f,0.0f,0.0f);
        float shininessRSphere = 20.0f;
        Appearance redSphereApp = new Appearance();
        redSphereApp.setMaterial(new Material(ambientColourRSphere,emissiveColourRSphere,
                             diffuseColourRSphere,specularColourRSphere,shininessRSphere));
        objRoot.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot.addChild(objTrans);
        sphere = new Sphere(0.15f,redSphereApp);
        objTrans = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans.addChild(sphere);
        objRoot.addChild(objTrans);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere
                (new Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0),100.0);
        Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(0.2f,0.2f,1.0f);
        Vector3f light1Direction = new Vector3f(+4.0f,-7.0f,-12.0f);
        DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight
                (light1Color,light1Direction);
        light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        objRoot.addChild(light1);
        Color3f ambientColor = new Color3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        AmbientLight ambientLightNode = new AmbientLight(ambientColor);
        ambientLightNode.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        objRoot.addChild(ambientLightNode); 
        Color3f bgColor = new Color3f(0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        Background bg = new Background(bgColor);
        bg.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
        objRoot.addChild(bg);
        return objRoot;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph2(){
        objRoot2.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans2 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans2.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot2.addChild(objTrans2);
        sphere2 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans2 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans2.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans2.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans2.addChild(sphere2);
        objRoot2.addChild(objTrans2);
        return objRoot2;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph3(){
        objRoot3.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans3 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans3.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot3.addChild(objTrans3);
        sphere3 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans3 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans3.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans3.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans3.addChild(sphere3);
        objRoot3.addChild(objTrans3);
        return objRoot3;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph4(){
        objRoot4.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans4 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans4.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot4.addChild(objTrans4);
        sphere4 = new Sphere(0.45f);
        objTrans4 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans4.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans4.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans4.addChild(sphere4);
        objRoot4.addChild(objTrans4);
        return objRoot4;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph5(){
        objRoot5.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans5 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans5.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot5.addChild(objTrans5);
        sphere5 = new Sphere(0.45f);
        objTrans5 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans5.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans5.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans5.addChild(sphere5);
        objRoot5.addChild(objTrans5);
        return objRoot5;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph6(){
        objRoot6.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans6 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans6.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot6.addChild(objTrans6);
        sphere6 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans6 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans6.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans6.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans6.addChild(sphere6);
        objRoot6.addChild(objTrans6);
        return objRoot6;
    }

    public BranchGroup createSceneGraph7(){
        objRoot7.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH);
        objTrans7 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans7.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        objRoot7.addChild(objTrans7);
        sphere7 = new Sphere(0.18f);
        objTrans7 = new TransformGroup();
        objTrans7.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        Transform3D pos1 = new Transform3D();
        pos1.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
        objTrans7.setTransform(pos1);
        objTrans7.addChild(sphere7);
        objRoot7.addChild(objTrans7);
        return objRoot7;
    }

    BallJump(){
        setFocusable(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        c = new Canvas3D(config);
        Color color = new Color(0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        setBackground(color);
        scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + score);     
        scoreLabel.setBackground(color);       
        add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START,scoreLabel);
        add("Center",c);
        c.addKeyListener(this);
        c.setSize(585,560);
        timer = new Timer(60,this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(100);
        timer.start();
        scene = createSceneGraph();
        scene2 = createSceneGraph2();
        scene3 = createSceneGraph3();
        scene4 = createSceneGraph4();
        scene5 = createSceneGraph5();
        scene6 = createSceneGraph6();
        scene7 = createSceneGraph7();
        u = new SimpleUniverse(c);
        u.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        u.addBranchGraph(scene);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene2);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene3);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene4);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene5);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene6);
        u.addBranchGraph(scene7);
        float randomSpawn1 = (float) Math.random() * -3.7f + -4.1f;
        float randomSpawn2 = (float) Math.random() * 2.5f + 3.1f; 
        float randomSpawn3 = (float) Math.random() * -2.7f + -5.1f;
        float randomSpawn4 = (float) Math.random() * 2.5f + 4.1f; 
        float randomSpawn5 = (float) Math.random() * -5.7f + -15.1f;
        float randomSpawn6 = (float) Math.random() * 5.7f + 18.1f; 
        rightX = randomSpawn2;
        right = randomSpawn4;
        leftX = randomSpawn1;
        left = randomSpawn3;
        rightX2 = randomSpawn6;
        leftX2 = randomSpawn5;
        rightDx = -.05f;
        leftDx = .05f;  
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'd'|e.getKeyChar() == 'D'|e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_RIGHT){
            xloc = xloc + .1f;
        }

        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'a'|e.getKeyChar() == 'A'|e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT){
            xloc = xloc - .1f;
        }
    }    

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        height += .1f * sign;
        if(Math.abs(height * 2) >= 1)
            sign = -1.0f * sign;
        height2 += .1f * sign2;
        if(Math.abs(height2 * 2) >= 1)
            sign2 = -1.0f * sign2;
        Vector3d vec;
        int thing = 1;
        int thing2 = 2;
        if(height < -.4f){
          vec = new Vector3d(1.0,.7,1.0);
        }else{
          vec = new Vector3d(1.0,1.0,1.0);
          thing = 2;
        }
        trans.setScale(vec);
        trans.setTranslation(new Vector3f(xloc,height - .15f,0.0f));
        objTrans.setTransform(trans);
        if(height < -.10f){
          vec = new Vector3d(1.0,1.0,1.0);
          thing2 = 1;
        }
        if(height < -.4f){
          trans.setScale(new Vector3d(1.0,1.0,1.0));
        }
        if(score >= 1000){
            rightDx = -.06f;
            leftDx = .06f; 
        }
        if(score >= 2000){
            rightDx = -.07f;
            leftDx = .07f; 
        }
        if(score >= 4000){
            rightDx = -.08f;
            leftDx = .08f; 
        }
        if(score >= 5000){
            rightDx = -.09f;
            leftDx = .09f; 
        }
        if(score >= 10000){
            rightDx = -.1f;
            leftDx = .1f; 
        }
        if(score >= 15000){
            rightDx = -.12f;
            leftDx = .12f; 
        }
        Vector3f vector = new Vector3f(rightX += rightDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector);
        objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector2 = new Vector3f(leftX += leftDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector2);
        objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector3 = new Vector3f(rightX2 += rightDx,-.4f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector3);
        objTrans4.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector4 = new Vector3f(leftX2 += leftDx,-.4f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector4);
        objTrans5.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector5 = new Vector3f(right += rightDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector5);
        objTrans6.setTransform(trans);
        Vector3f vector6 = new Vector3f(left += leftDx,-.7f,0.0f);
        trans.setTranslation(vector6);
        objTrans7.setTransform(trans);
        float leftXDistance = vector2.x - xloc - .22f;
        float leftXDistancez = vector6.x - xloc - .22f;
        float leftXDistance2 = vector4.x - xloc;
        float yDistance2 = -.5f - height;
        float xDistance2 = vector3.x - xloc;
        float xDistance = vector.x - xloc + .22f;
        float yDistance = -.7f - height;
        float xDistance3 = vector5.x - xloc + .22f;
        double leftdistance = Math.sqrt((leftXDistance * leftXDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance));
        double leftdistancez = Math.sqrt((leftXDistancez * leftXDistancez) + (yDistance * yDistance));
        double leftdistance2 = Math.sqrt((leftXDistance2 * leftXDistance2) + (yDistance2 * yDistance2));
        double distance2 = Math.sqrt((xDistance2 * xDistance2) + (yDistance2 * yDistance2));
        double distance = Math.sqrt((xDistance * xDistance) + (yDistance * yDistance));
        double distance3 = Math.sqrt((xDistance3 * xDistance3) + (yDistance * yDistance));
        if(distance < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){     
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 2.5f + 3.1f;
                rightX = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector);
                objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                objRoot.detach();
                setAlive(false);
                isAlive = false;
                isEndscreen = false;
            }
        }
        if(leftdistance < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){      
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -2.7f + -3.3f;
                leftX = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector2);
                objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                objRoot.detach();
                setAlive(false);
                isAlive = false;
                isEndscreen = false;
            }
        }
        if(leftdistancez < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){  
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -2.5f + -3.1f;
                left = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector6);
                objTrans7.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                objRoot.detach();
                setAlive(false);
                isAlive = false;
                isEndscreen = false;
            }
        }
        if(leftdistance2 < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){  
                score += 200;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -4.5f + -12.1f;
                leftX2 = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector4);
                objTrans5.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                objRoot.detach();
                setAlive(false);
                isAlive = false;
                isEndscreen = false;
            }
        }
        if(distance2 < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){ 
                score += 200;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 4.5f + 15.1f;
                rightX2 = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector3);
                objTrans4.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                objRoot.detach();
                setAlive(false);
                isAlive = false;
                isEndscreen = false;
            }
        }
        if(distance3 < vec.x / 2 + .09f){
            if(thing == 2){
                score += 100;
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
                float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 2.5f + 3.1f;
                right = randomSpawn;
                trans.setTranslation(vector5);
                objTrans6.setTransform(trans);
            }
            if(thing == 1){
                objRoot.detach();
                isAlive = false;
                isEndscreen = false;
            }
        }
        if(rightX < -1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 1.5f + 2.1f;
            rightX = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector);
            objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(leftX > 1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.1f;
            leftX = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector2);
            objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(right < -1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 1.5f + 2.1f;
            right = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector);
            objTrans2.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(left > 1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.1f;
            left = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector2);
            objTrans3.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(rightX2 < -1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * 1.5f + 2.1f;
            rightX2 = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector3);
            objTrans4.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(leftX2 > 1.5f){
            float randomSpawn = (float) Math.random() * -1.5f + -2.1f;
            leftX2 = randomSpawn;
            trans.setTranslation(vector4);
            objTrans5.setTransform(trans);
        }
        if(xloc > .8f){
            xloc = .8f;
        }
        if(xloc < -.8f){
            xloc = -.8f;
        }
        if(!isAlive && !isEndscreen){
            endScreen();
            timer.stop();
            score = 0;
        }
    }

    public void endScreen(){
        isEndscreen = true;
        remove(scoreLabel);
        remove(c);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,1));
        Font font = new Font("Helvatica",Font.BOLD,24);
        label = new JLabel("      Your Score: " + score);  
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Press Space To Restart");
        label2.setFont(font);
        label.setFont(font);
        setBackground(Color.white);    
        add(BorderLayout.NORTH,label);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER,label2);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

and this is my Manifest txt:

```
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.2\lib\ext\vecmath.jar;C:\Users\Censored\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java24\build\classes\Game\Main.class
```

Comment: What class is your main method in? You should add that to your classpath.

Comment: @JesanFafon It still doesn't work

Comment: Before i give an answer, because there could be many reasons for this error try one thing for me. remove the .class at the end of the Main.class in your manifest. tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and i think it has to do with the packages name. Try changing your main class'es name into the packages name without spaces